# "Equalize" as a substitute for "counterbalance"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, prepositions

When I say "This is equalized by that" is this the correct way to express that the weight of "that" is equal to the weight of "this"? And I want to stress here that "that" is used to cancel out the effects of "this" metaphorically.
I've made some research into the usage of "equalize", but couldn't find a example of its usage where you use another object to convey the comparison of weight of the two.

"This is counterbalanced by that" should be correct word here, but I don't like it stylistically. Using "balance" instead of "counterbalance" seems like an option, but stylistically it seems too neutral and inexpressive.
I've also seen "outweigh" as a synonym for "counterbalance" but if anything, it creates an impression that one thing has greater in weight than the other on the first read, and I don't want that.

More specific example: "The achievements of people equalized/counterbalanced/outweighed by government's corruption."

Comment: [*Equalized*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equalized) can be used in many contexts. Weights can be equalized, lengths can be equalized, and salaries can be equalized. All you have to do is say *what* is being equalized. In your case, *its effects are equalized …*

Comment: Your example sentence is far too generic and vague. The idiomatic use of a word is governed by the context and there are very, very few true synonyms in English - each word has its nuance. **You need to give a specific example.** As it stands, *"This is equalized by that"* does not sound idiomatic at all. And I cannot agree with *Using "balance" instead of "counterbalance" seems ... too neutral and inexpressive.*

Comment: @Greybeard I've added an example: "The achievements of people equalized/counterbalanced/outweighed by government's corruption."

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is ambiguous. **1** "to outweigh" is the converse of *equalise* and *counterbalance*, not a close synonym. **2** You seem to be using equalised as (i) an adjective or (ii) the passive form without an active verb ("to be"). The result is that the example is a phrase (rather than a sentence) with the meaning of "The achievements of people **that were/are** made the same by government's corruption..." **3** To equalise does not mean "to be equal to.".

Comment: The term "[contravened](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/contravene)" might fit your example.